# Backport Python 3.4's regular expression "fullmatch()" to Python 2

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.x, backport

Python 3.4 introduced the new regex method [`re.fullmatch(pattern, string, flags=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch).

Has anyone back-ported this new method to older Python versions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To make sure that the entire string matches, you need to use the `\Z` [end-of-string anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
def fullmatch(regex, string, flags=0):
    """Emulate python-3.4 re.fullmatch()."""
    return re.match("(?:" + regex + r")\Z", string, flags=flags)
```

The `\A` anchor is not necessary since `re.match()` already anchors the match to the start of the string.

Comment: Can also use `$` to match until end-of-line.

Comment: @gaborous: That might backfire since `regex` could contain a `(?m)` modifier, and then less than the entire string could match.

Comment: Does the `r")\Z"` part need to be a raw string literal, or maybe this is just a habit of yours? Neither Python 2 nor 3 treat `\Z` in any special way, so I think this is not mandatory, but who knows...

Answer (score 2):

Here it is my backporting, which has at least one problem (thanks [tim-pietzcker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20670/tim-pietzcker)) but *does not require recompiling regexes*:

```
import re

def fullmatch(regex, string, flags=0):
    """Emulate python-3.4 re.fullmatch()."""
    m = re.match(regex, string, flags=flags)
    if m and m.span()[1] == len(string):
        return m
```

And here are some test-cases proving the above emulation-function.

```
def compare_expansion(regex, s, template):
    m1 = re.fullmatch(regex, s)
    s1 = m1.expand(template) if m1 else '<NO-MATCH>'
    m2 = fullmatch(regex, s)
    s2 = m2.expand(template) if m2 else '<NO-MATCH>'
    if s1 != s2:
        raise AssertionError("\n  PY-3: '%s' \n  PY-2: '%s' " % (s1, s2))

compare_expansion('.*', 'foo', r'A')
compare_expansion('(.*)', 'foo', r'A_\1')
compare_expansion('(.*)', 'foo', r'A_\g<0>')

compare_expansion('a.*', 'afoo&', r'A')
compare_expansion('a(\w*)', 'afoo&', r'A_\1')
compare_expansion('a(\w*)', 'afoo&', r'A_\g<0>')

## But this fails!
compare_expansion(".*?", "Hello", '\g<0>')
AssertionError: 
  PY-3: 'A_Hello' 
  PY-2: '<NO-MATCH>'
```

Comment: This fails with lazy quantifiers: `re.fullmatch(".*?", "Hello")` returns `None` where it should return a match.