# `setattr()` on Python2 `_sre.SRE_Pattern`

Tags: python-2.7, setattr

I'm basically attempting py2/3 compatibility by trying to add a a `fullmatch` method to Python2 `re` compiled patterns.

I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/2982/2694385 on how to add an attribute to an existing instance.
I'm creating the method as given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30212799/2694385.

Example code

```
import re
import six


regex = re.compile('some pattern')  # Better if we keep this same

if six.PY2:
    def fullmatch(self_regex, string, flags=0):
        return self_regex.match(string, flags=flags)

    regex = re.compile(r'(?:' + regex.pattern + r')\Z', flags=regex.flags)

    import types

    bound = types.MethodType(fullmatch, regex)
    # AttributeError here. None of the following three lines work
    regex.fullmatch = bound
    regex.__setattr__('fullmatch', bound)
    setattr(regex, 'fullmatch', bound)
```

Comment: @zwer Can you make it an answer. I have ended up doing `re.fullmatch = fullmatch`  for now, and using `re.fullmatch(regex, string)` instead of `regex.fullmatch(string)` for now.

Answer (score 0):

That ain't gonna work - regex objects are created on the C side and they don't represent your regular instances so you cannot modify their signature from within Python. For example, if you try to extend `_sre.SRE_Pattern`:

```
import _sre

class CustomPattern(_sre.SRE_Pattern): pass
```

You'll get an `AttributeError` complaining that such object doesn't exist in the `_sre` module. If you try to cheat it with:

```
import re

tmp_pattern = re.compile("")
sre_pat = type(tmp_pattern)

class CustomPattern(sre_pat): pass
```

it will give you a `TypeError` complaining that `_sre.SRE_Pattern` (which now 'temporarily' exists as it's being created ad-hoc) is not an acceptable base type.

What you can do instead is to create a full wrapper around the `re` module (or at least add the missing structures to it) and handle the Python version differences on the Python's side, although I think it's just not worth it.

P.S. If you're not using `six` anywhere else, there no reason for the overhead just to check your Python version - you can use `sys.version_info.major < 3` instead.

Answer (score 0):

See [nlpia.regexes.Pattern](https://github.com/totalgood/nlpia/blob/master/src/nlpia/regexes.py) for something similar to what you want -- a Frankenstein mashup of `_sre.Pattern` with a `fullmatch()` method. This monkey-patching "inheritance" approach works in Python 2 and 3.

```
import re
import regex

class Pattern:
    """ "Inherits" _sre.SRE_Pattern and adds .fullmatch() method

    >>> pattern = Pattern('Aaron[ ]Swartz')
    >>> pattern.match('Aaron Swartz')
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 12), match='Aaron Swartz'>
    >>> pattern.fullmatch('Aaron Swartz!!')
    >>> pattern.match('Aaron Swartz!!')
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 12), match='Aaron Swartz'>
    """
    def __init__(self, pattern):
        self._compiled_pattern = re.compile(pattern)
        for name in dir(self._compiled_pattern):
            if not name in set(('__class__', '__init__', 'fullmatch')):
                attr = getattr(self._compiled_pattern, name)
                setattr(self, name, attr)

def fullmatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return regex.fullmatch(self._compiled_pattern.pattern, *args, **kwargs)
```